# Summary/Table of Content Slide in Powerpoint 2013

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I have been trying to create a slide for a 100+ slide deck. Earlier they used to have an automatic summary slide option in the slide sorter view. But I am unable to find it in Powerpoint 2013.

I am aware it was taken out in 2010,2007 but it is not mentioned anywhere that it is unavailable in 2013.

Comment: does it related to graphic design?

Comment: I'm not aware of such a summary in PPT 2013

Comment: It's reasonable to assume that once a feature's been removed, you're not likely to see it reappear in a later version.  There are a couple of resources to get around this on this page of my PowerPoint FAQ site: http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00615_Create_a_table_of_contents_-TOC-_slide_with_links.htm

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps to create a Table of Contents slide in PowerPoint 2013.

1. First activate the Outline View. *View* (Ribbon Tab) -> *Presentation View*s (Group) -> *Outline View* (Button).
2. In the left pane, you will see your presentation outline.
3. Right-click in the Outline and click on *Collapse*. Then click on *Collapse All*. This will display only the Slide Titles in your presentation.
4. Highlight the Slide Titles or press Ctrl+A to select all of the slides in your presentation. And, then press Ctrl+C to copy.

[image: Outline-view-titles-highlighted]

5. Create a new Table of Contents slide and click in the Content Placeholder Box and press Ctrl+V to paste. You may need to follow these steps a couple of times if you have many slides to include in your Table of Contents.

Comment: Note that you have to paste as text in step 5. For instance, in PowerPoint 2016 for Mac, pressing Cmd+V copies the slides themselves, not the titles. Cmd+Ctrl+V allows you to paste as unformatted text, which pastes the titles.

Answer (score -1):

You can find one here: 
https://vu2s.jimdo.com/comment-faire-how-does-it-work/

It is in English (even if  Jimdo does not always translate the page).
I wrote it and guarantee: no ad, no virus, no Bulls…
Has been tested and tested and tested.
You have different types of TOC lines.
Specially made for BIG documents:  creates TOC on several pages.
It is a POWERPOINT extension, with explanations on how to install on the site.
Hopes it helps
Philippe